Why can't I update a memo field AsString() in OnCalcFields in state dsInternalCalc?
procedure TDataModuleProviders.FTPDataCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  inherited;

  with DataSet do
  begin
    if (State = dsInternalCalc) then
    begin
      FieldByName(SProvFTPPassword).AsString    := 'something'  // String field, fine
      FieldByName(SProvFTPPrivateKey).AsString  := 'test';      // Memo field
      

The last line gives a 'Dataset not in edit or insert mode' with call stack:

How can I update the calculated field of type memo here?
Delphi 12, 64-bit
The dataset is an in-memory TClientDataSet

IIRC, TClientDataSet simply doesn't support that.
